# How to use data from a api (json) in react

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

I am making a simple weather app with react and typescript.

I want to know how to display simple data fetched from a public api in react and typescript. This api is in a json format. URL(`https://data.buienradar.nl/2.0/feed/json`)

How do you use api data in react?
What I have tried is calling the get forecast function inside a paragraph.

```
<p>Forecast: {getForecast} </p>
```

---

Source code of the forecast component.

```
import React from 'react';


const Forecast = () => {
    function getForecast() {
        return fetch("https://data.buienradar.nl/2.0/feed/json")
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((data) => {return data.forecast})
        // .then((data) => {return data});
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Take weatherdata from the api</h2>
            <div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={getForecast}>Take weather data from the api</button>
            <p>Forecast:  {getForecast}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Forecast;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UseState() is the react hook method, which helps to achieve it. Check the below code for reference.

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const Forecast = () => {
    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState();
    function getForecast() {
        return fetch("https://data.buienradar.nl/2.0/feed/json")
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((data) => {return setForecast(data.forecast)})
        // .then((data) => {return data});
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Take weatherdata from the api</h2>
            <div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={getForecast}>Take weather data from the api</button>
            <p>Forecast:  {forecast}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Forecast;
```